# CEDET semantic is too slow to find candidates of the header files of libraries

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, tags, global, cedet

I am using the [glew](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) and [freeglut](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/) libraries (both of which include huge numbers of functions and constants declarations) to write opengl programs under Emacs. I use the `CEDET`'s default `semanticdb` as the back end of `auto-complete` at first. However the Emacs freezes and it cost about 20 seconds to pop the candidates of `auto-complete` when I typing `gl`(since there is many `GL_XXX` constants and `glxxx` function in the header files of `glew` and `glut`). the pop-up of the candidate is too slow, is there a way to speed it up still using the `CEDET`? or is there another way to walk around it? by using the gtags? how?

Since there are so many functions and constants declarations in the header files, I am heavily rely on the auto completion. I am using the `CEDET` 1.1, does the new version of `CEDET` solve the problem?

Comment: Please post a simple example showing the problem on the CEDET mailing list. I know those GL-headers and they're crazy; there may not be a solution to your problem, but I'd need to reproduce it first.

Comment: For c/c++ there are clang-based completion packages. You may want to check them out: http://root42.blogspot.com/2012/07/nice-c-autocomplete-configuration-for.html

Comment: @pokita I need to test it in the newer version of `CEDET`, if the problem still exists, I think I will put the problem on the mailing list.

Comment: @Tom thanks for reply. I use GNU Emacs on Windows with MinGW, is it work on the Windows platform?

Comment: AFAIK there is clang for windows, so it should work there too.

Comment: @pokita posted on the CEDET mailing list https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3608445&group_id=17886&atid=117886 ID:3608445

Answer (score 1):

Use of gtags should potentially speedup calculation of alternatives. Does slow completion happens always, or only on first use? This could be caused by parsing header files, etc., and later this should be caches in semanticdb (if you've enabled it)

Comment: I just tested it, Yes you're right, the very slow completion happens only once, but the subsequent completion is not fast either, it take about 5 seconds to pop the pop-up. I just used the gtags, and the result is not very good, I think, since it cost about 3 seconds to pop the pop-up. is there some better solutions?

Comment: I'm not sure right now, there was an idea to rewrite parts of cedet/semantic in compiled language...